# Using context free grammar to work with propositional logic symbols

Tags: context-free-grammar, discrete-mathematics, propositional-calculus

i'm currently trying to use a context free grammar for propositional logic.

Im imagining that the set of terminals will looks like this:

```
T=(q,p,¬,∧,∨,→,⟷).
```

Now what i need is to define a set of productions, that can help me in achieving all legal compound propositions. 
Can anyone help me? I really dont know where to start, the high amount of terminals is kinda throwing me off

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might help to start by reducing the scope of your problem. Specifically, can you write a CFG for expressions when the only allowed symbols are p, q, and ∧? In that case, every expression is either

- a single propositional variable, or
- a conjunction (∧) of two expressions.

That would give something like this:

> E → p | q | E ∧ E

Now, how would you add in the ability to use ∨? How about the other symbols? See if you can take it from here.

Comment: would you only have E as both starting symbol, and the only non-terminal?

Comment: and i guess, bulding upon what you just wrote, I would add disjuncts like this
E → p | q | E ∧ E | E ∨ E

almost seems to simple to be true

Comment: This will generate all the possible strings. It is, however, an *ambiguous grammar* in the sense that you can derive p /\ q \/ p in two different ways ((p /\ q) \/ p) versus p /\ (q \/ p)). If that matters, you can use a technique called *layering* to remove this ambiguity.